# Chat room can be created with no clickable name

Tags: bug, chat

A [chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/867/2015/5/14) can be [renamed](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3445565#3445565) to contain only a zero-width space as the title of the room. This gives the room no clickable name for easy entry

> [Initially I named the room with zero-width space, then realised that I can have completely nameless room and now it has no name at all :)](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3448468#3448468)

[image: Chat room with no name]

There is a work around to get into the room:

- Click the number in the lower right to get to the transcript
- Click join users in this room from the transcript

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this."

Comment: I have no witty retort @AnnaLear. I'm disappointed in myself. I'm going to blame it on being late on a Friday.

Comment: I was not the one that did this though, it was something I noticed.

Comment: Please have the witty retort on my desk by Monday. ;)

Comment: Info -> Join Room as well, for workaround.

Comment: Can confirm the bug and the workarounds having been in that room. Also, chat notification become unclear too, since the room name and link will be missing (as expected since no name exist).

Had though this was already reported by original discoverers, but since this was not the case I am voting this now.

Comment: Not very different from users with no clickable name. Blame should be on those abusing it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you would like to disallow creating rooms with zero-names?

Answer (score 2):

Seem it is worse.

You can actually game the system on the room creation too (no need to rename) by using a Zero-Width-Space char.

When correcting the bug, please keep this in mind and add a validation check on room creation too.

Probably room names should be stripped of any non-printable character.